# Does my property update my field or am I using MVVM incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out MVVM and WPF and I wanted to test some easy code to get the hang of it.

I've done this before so I thought that this wouldn't be a problem but I'm losing my mind cause of this.

**This is not the full code but I've toned it down just for the specific problem**

I have a model

```
private string _btnName;
public string BtnName { get {return _btnName;} set{ _btnName = value; } }
```

And my view model like this

```
BtnName {get { return model.BtnName;} set{ model.BtnName = value;}}
ICommand ChangeButtonName = new RelayCommand(ChangeName)

Public void ChangeName(object a){ BtnName = "test"; }
```

And the view like this

```
<Button Content={Binding MV.BtnName} Command={Binding MV.ChangeButtonName}/>
```

Where `MV` is my **ViewModel** Class and `model` is my **Model** Class.

When I click on the button it goes into my function and does indeed "change" name, but on the view the button will still have the old content. Meaning that it doesn't update.

And I don't understand why.

- **Why does my button not update the content text?**
- **Should I have properties in my ViewModel?**

Comment: You must notify the UI that the property changed,see [this](https://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html) for example. Or better [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91c28d/implement-change-notification-using-inotifypropertychanged-i/)

Comment: and you must not set the button content with your VM; better use translate system in place

Comment: What do you mean with translate system? @GCamel

Comment: well, either it is a data (then property ButtonName means nothing) or it is just to translate the content of the button...then it is better so search for a solution to manage your resources/translation and doing it in xaml / not with viewmodel

Comment: @GCamel Ah Yes I was wondering if I really did the correct thing to set properties in my ViewModel. It would be better to set the buttons content with my model instead of my viewmodel correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RelayCommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And you have to change your property to notify your View when the property was updated.

```
private string _btnName;
public string BtnName { get { return _btnName; } set { _btnName = value; OnPropertyChanged("BtnName"); } }
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `nameof(BtnName)` instead of `"BtnName"`, to ensure that a correct (property) name is used.